# Is this function non-decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $u:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $u\in C^1((0,1))$, $u\geq 0$, $u(0)=0$ and $u(1)>0$. Also, suppose that for all $\phi\in C_0^\infty((0,1))$ with $\phi\geq 0$, we have that $$\int _0^1u'(t)\phi'(t)\leq 0$$

Can we conclude that $u'$ is non-decreasing?

Comment: Sorry, $\phi\geq 0$

Comment: What does the $0$ on $C_0^\infty$ mean on $[0,1]$?

Comment: The support of $\phi$ is contained in $(0,1)$.

Comment: Can't you use a Dirac sequence to get that $f'(a)\leq 0$ for all $a\in (0,1)$?

Comment: Yes. I think that's the meaning of say that $u$ is a distributional solution of the inequality $(u')'\geq 0$.

Comment: There is the constraint that $\int \phi' = 0$.

Comment: By mean value theorem, there's $\alpha\in(0,1)$ such that $u(1)=u'(\alpha)>0$ and by continuity of $u'$ we find an interval $(\alpha-\epsilon,\alpha+\epsilon)$ where $u'\geq0$.

Comment: @copper.hat If $u$ is $C^2$ and $u''\geq 0$, then $u'$ is non-decreasing and for all $\phi\geq 0$ ,$\phi\in C_0^\infty(0,1)$, we have that $$\int _0^1u'(t)\phi'(t)\leq 0$$ Now I want to know if $u'$ is non-decreasing with less hypothesis (in the sense of distributions)